# Navigating error in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer, material-design

I am trying to implement a Material Navigation Drawer. Something like this https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template.

I have two Questions.

1.I am declaring all the intent in the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` method in my `main Activity`. If my main activity is directed to another activity such as `FeedActivity`. Then do i have to declare different `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` method in my `feedActivity`.

2.When i pass the `MainActivity` intent in the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` Method. The App is not working correctly.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks{

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        if (position == 1){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FeedListActivity.class));
        }else if (position == 2){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
.If i pass this below code in the above method. The App is not going to FeedActivity. It is opening the mainActivity Again. when i press the 1st item in the list.

```
if (position == 0){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
```

If the question is not clear, sorry for that.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In question #2 please clarify what you mean by app is not working correctly, and app works differently...when you replace with the code at the bottom.  Are you getting an error (what error), is wrong activity starting? etc...

Comment: if you are going to have navigation drawer in several activities, then you have to implement the methods in each of them. It is better to use fragments instead of various activities in this case for example. I don't understand the second question. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

-#1  An new activity would have implement a new drawer, along with a new drawer layout.  It's simply a design pattern that should never exists.  If you have a persistent navigation drawer, it should wrap a fragment, and you should be swapping out that fragment.

If you went the activity route, you would have to recreate the navigation drawer in every activity, with a new drawer listener.  Think of activity's as completely replacing the old one, while fragments only replace a part of the screen.

-#2  The first item on the list is the 0th position item.  It's zero-based indexing.  I think the problem is your index is off by one.

Comment: I think u haven't go the 2nd one Right? I am just using the position ==0. But when position 1 is pressed it goes to main Activity ?

Comment: okay, what does it do when you press the position after that.